# How to convert a list of items to lists of fixed size in scala

Tags: scala, list, split, sublist

I have a list of an indefinite items. I need to split them into lists of fixed size in scala.

Imagine there are 450 items in a list and I need to divide it into 4 lists of 100 items each. How do we achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, but List(...).grouped(100) might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with `grouped(size: Int)`.

Example:

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
println(l.grouped(2).toSeq) // --> Stream(List(1, 2), ?)
println(l.grouped(2).toList) // --> List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5, 6), List(7, 8), List(9, 10))
```

From `IterableLike` ([ScalaDoc](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.html)):

```
  /** Partitions elements in fixed size ${coll}s.
   *  @see [[scala.collection.Iterator]], method `grouped`
   *
   *  @param size the number of elements per group
   *  @return An iterator producing ${coll}s of size `size`, except the
   *          last will be less than size `size` if the elements don't divide evenly.
   */
  def grouped(size: Int): Iterator[Repr] = ...
```

Comment: Why someone down vote this? it looks the correct answer to me

Comment: I am also interested - why this is downvoted - as I want to improve my answers.

Comment: I gave you an upvote. This looks correct to me. I also don't understand why the question itself is downvoted.

Comment: If you are expecting all the lists of fixed size, then `grouped(n:Int)` doesn't work as the last group could be having lesser number of elements.